# I can't see Docker image in openshift services

Tags: java, docker, openshift

I have created docker image using this Docker file:

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/14/jdk/ubuntu/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#               NOTE: THIS DOCKERFILE IS GENERATED VIA "build_latest.sh" or "update_multiarch.sh"
#
#                       PLEASE DO NOT EDIT IT DIRECTLY.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata curl ca-certificates fontconfig locales \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_VERSION jdk-14.0.2+12

RUN set -eux; \
    ARCH="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; \
    case "${ARCH}" in \
       aarch64|arm64) \
         ESUM='ee87e9f03b1fbe6f328429b78fe1a9f44900026d220c90dfd747fe0bcd62d904'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk14-binaries/releases/download/jdk-14.0.2%2B12/OpenJDK14U-jdk_aarch64_linux_hotspot_14.0.2_12.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       armhf|armv7l) \
         ESUM='65f193496c6977ba7aed1563edc4b5be091b5ff03e3d790074bb4e389a034b36'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk14-binaries/releases/download/jdk-14.0.2%2B12/OpenJDK14U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_14.0.2_12.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       ppc64el|ppc64le) \
         ESUM='465a3b8e931896b8d95e452d479615c4bf543535c05b6ea246323ae114e67d7d'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk14-binaries/releases/download/jdk-14.0.2%2B12/OpenJDK14U-jdk_ppc64le_linux_hotspot_14.0.2_12.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       s390x) \
         ESUM='7d27aea30e359cf0bb561f8dcca6f4591dbc3ae831981f8a19aa367d31a9709b'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk14-binaries/releases/download/jdk-14.0.2%2B12/OpenJDK14U-jdk_s390x_linux_hotspot_14.0.2_12.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       amd64|x86_64) \
         ESUM='7d5ee7e06909b8a99c0d029f512f67b092597aa5b0e78c109bd59405bbfa74fe'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk14-binaries/releases/download/jdk-14.0.2%2B12/OpenJDK14U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_14.0.2_12.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       *) \
         echo "Unsupported arch: ${ARCH}"; \
         exit 1; \
         ;; \
    esac; \
    curl -LfsSo /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz ${BINARY_URL}; \
    echo "${ESUM} */tmp/openjdk.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    mkdir -p /opt/java/openjdk; \
    cd /opt/java/openjdk; \
    tar -xf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz --strip-components=1; \
    rm -rf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz;

ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk \
    PATH="/opt/java/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
CMD ["jshell"]
```

After that I have pushed my image to OpenShift Online integrated container registry, according to commands in openshift, following about section screen below.

[image]

I can see my container in deployments up and running.

[image]

But I can't see it in services.

[image]

Maybe someone will know answer to my questions.

What I did wrong?

What I have to add to the container to make it visible in openshift services?

If You have any Dockerfile creating a container with openjdk 14 or 15 appearing in openshift services and You can shere it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Service` is separate from a `Pod`. So you will need to create the `Service` separately. Typically, with OpenShift, people use the `oc new-app` command line tool ([see the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html#specifying-an-image)). This will automatically create the `Service` for you.

If you want to create a new `Service`, you can either do that by using the `oc create service` command line so:

```
oc create service clusterip backend
```

Or you can create it by specifying the `Service` in a YAML and apply it using `oc apply -f <filename>`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Note that you may need to change the `selector`, `port` or `targetPort` above. As the next step, often you want to expose the Service to the outside world, this is then typically done with a Route in Openshift (`oc expose service <service-name>` will create the Route for you).

> What I have to add to the container to make it visible in openshift services?

As outlined above, a `Service` is different from a `Pod` and thus the container definition has nothing to do with the `Service`. I would recommend that you re-create your Pod using `oc new-app`, that will automatically create the `Service` for you.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering.

I've tried with **quay.io/wildfly/wildfly-runtime-centos7** image and it worked.
I assume that this image has `kind:Service` definition somewhere.

Container showed up in services, my Dockerfile content below.

```
FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly-runtime-centos7:latest
USER root

# install openjdk 14
RUN mkdir /tmp/tools

RUN curl -o /tmp/tools/jdk.tar.gz -L https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk14/ri/openjdk-14+36_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \ 
    tar -zxvf /tmp/tools/jdk.tar.gz -C /tmp/tools

RUN mv /tmp/tools/jdk-14/* /usr/lib/jvm 
RUN rm /tmp/tools/jdk.tar.gz

ENV PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/bin:${PATH}"
ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm" 

COPY ./target/backend-*-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/backend.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/backend.jar"]
```

My commands.

Build docker image.

```
docker build -t backend .
```

I have test it, running container locally.

```
docker run -it backend
```

Push to openshift.

```
docker tag backend:latest registry.pro-eu-west-1.openshift.com/<MY-PROJECT-NAME>/backend

docker login registry.pro-eu-west-1.openshift.com -u $(oc whoami) -p $(oc whoami -t)

docker push registry.pro-eu-west-1.openshift.com/MY-PROJECT-NAME>/backend
```